# Maximum call stack size exceeded. recursive tags

Tags: javascript, tags, riot.js

My object looks like this:

```
<app>
  <child opts="{ json }"></child>
  <script>
    this.json = [
      {
        text: 'parent',
        child: [
          {
            text: 'child1',
            child: {
              text: 'child2'
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    ];
  </script>
</app>
```

Each child can have its own children. So I need recursion tag here. It is what I have:

```
<child>
<h1>child: { opts.opts.text }</h1>
<div if={opts.opts.child}>
    <child opts={opts.opts.child}></child>
</div>
</child>
```

I get `Maximum call stack size exceeded`. I read that in a riot js recursion tags is a problem, but did not find any solution, or that it can not be.

Comment: Could you add the code for `child` tag? Or if that is it then show how you are using it.

Comment: for now that's all. I want use recursive here because I can't know how many nesting child I will have.

Comment: I have to guess because your example is not complete. Is this what you have? -> http://plnkr.co/edit/07au1eYZOSjU1vldColC?p=preview

Comment: Yes, it is exactly what I have. Sorry I forgot to add this

Answer (score 0):

I've extended @Heikki's example here: http://plnkr.co/edit/12AyPoahb9vGOvx06qqv?p=preview

The data is structured a little differently:

```
this.json = {
  text: 'parent',
  children: [
    {
      text: 'child1',
      children: [{
        text: 'child2',
        children: [
          {text: 'Inner', children: [
            {
              text: 'Inner inner',
              children: []
            },
            {
              text: 'Inner inner 2',
              children: []
            }
          ]}
        ]
      }]
    }
  ]
};
```

With the updated child tag:

```
<child>
  <h1>Text: { this.opts.data.text }</h1>
  <virtual each={ child in this.opts.data.children }>
    <child data="{ child }"></child>
  </virtual>
</child>
```